# Keep my comment when I load a new edit

Tags: feature-request, comments, review

I was just in the "First posts" review queue, and as I was writing a longish comment on one of the posts, I saw the

> An edit has been made to this post. Click here to reload

bar at the top. Since I wanted to see if my comment was still accurate/relevant, I clicked on it. Unfortunately, this reloaded the entire page and my comment was lost.

Since I'm pretty active in the review queues, this is not the first time this is happened to me. It's also very obnoxious. I'm honestly not sure if this behavior is expected or not, so I don't know if this is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Either way, could we have it so our comments are kept when we load an edit from the review queues?

Comment: Has happened to me a few times, so I gave up "clicking to refresh" until I made a back up of my comment; usually just copying it to clipboard will be enough.

Comment: @NVZ: Or using something like [Lazarus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/) to do the same thing automatically.